# How calculate inverse of a matrix (3*1)

Tags: matrices, matlab

I'm a newbie of Matlab and non-native English language.

I have question what is inverse of matrix(3*1) such as

```
       1
       2
       3
```

I got an answer matrix(1*3)

```
  [1/14,   2/14,   3/14]
```

by Matlab

Can you help me How can calculate by hand???

Comment: The left and right inverses may be different (if they exist).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix (it is in a lot of other languages too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For non-square matrices, the inverse itself isn't well defined. Instead, you have a left inverse and a right inverse.  In particular, if $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, and $B$ and $C$ are $n \times m$ matrices with $AB = I_m$, $CA = I_n$ then $B$ is a right inverse of $A$ and $C$ is a left inverse.  The answer matlab seems to have given you is the left inverse, and is of course not unique.